# How to position an object in relation to another

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm working on rendering a model using SVG. I'll try to provide a clearer example than what I'm working on. Let's say the data structure is a JSON object as follows:

```
vehicle = {
    "axles": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "wheels": [
                {
                    "id": 0,
                    "diameter": 18
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "diameter": 18
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "wheels": [
                {
                    "id": 0,
                    "diameter": 18
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "diameter": 18
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to render some shape for the vehicle, each axle, and each wheel on that axle. I can successfully draw a shape for the vehicle and the axles, but not the wheels.

(I will ignore most styling/size properties)

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
svg.append("rect").attr("class", "car") // Only 1 car object
svg.selectAll(".car).data(vehicle.axles, function(d){return d.id}) // Render each axle
  .append("rect")
```

I want to then "draw the wheels" in relation to the position of the axle, but applying a data() to the end of the append statement puts the  inside of the axle's  element, having it not display - I need the wheel's  element to be in the parent  along with the axle's , but I need to read the child data of the axle in the data structure.

I hope this made any kind of sense and that someone can help out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't place a rectangle inside a rectangle, but you can place a group `g` inside another group. It makes sense to make the "car" a group, which contains a group for each "axle", which each contain a pair of "wheels" (which could be `rects`, or groups as well).

Instead of *chaining* all of your expressions, you can also assign a selection to a variable and reuse it, or `selectAll` elements by their selector (if the data you are binding doesn't depend on the previous context.) You can also use `each()` and repeat code for each element in a selection using `d3.select(this)` to refer to the parent element.

Here is an example. You can append the "car" as a group (and you can have any number of elements in it, including a `rect`):

```
svg.append("g").attr("class", "car") // this group is the car
   .append("rect")  // a rect inside the car group
   ...
```

Then you pre-select the "axle" objects you are going to create inside the "car" group:

```
svg.select(".car") // selects the group car (where we will append axles)
   .selectAll(".axle") // pre-select all axles
   .data(vehicle.axles)  // bind the data
   .enter()
   .append("g").attr("class", "axle") // will append new axle for each data item
      .each(function(d,i) {  // now repeat for each axle
          d3.select(this)  // selects the current axle
            .selectAll(".wheel")  // pre-select the wheels you are going to create
            .data(d.wheels) // bind the data
            .enter()
            .append("g").attr("class", "wheel") // append a wheel for the current axle
            .append("rect") // the rect representing the wheel
            ...
       })
       .append("rect") // the rect representing the axle
```

Try it out using this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/0anf5u11/). I replaced the `rects` for `text` and slightly modified the JSON data to illustrate the solution.

Comment: Excellent! My only issue now is that the hover pseudo class is being applied to all ancestors of an element when hovering over an element. If I have `.car:hover, .axle:hover, .wheel:hover{stroke: blue}`, hovering over only a wheel element will apply the hover pseudo class to every ancestor of it as well, ie. axle and car. I even tried moving the wheel element away from the other elements so nothing is overlapping and it still occurs.

Comment: EDIT: I fixed it, hah. I forgot the classes became classes for groups, not the rect's. Changed the style selectors to `.car rect:hover, .axle rect:hover, .wheel rect:hover{stroke: blue}`
Thanks again for the great answer!

Comment: You can also disable events on an element using CSS "pointer-events:none". This is useful when you are stacking layers and might want to ignore events on it (a typical example is text labels).